# Uncaught TypeError: CANNON.NaiveBroadPhase is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, cannon.js

i am learning cannon.js and i am have this error **Uncaught TypeError: CANNON.NaiveBroadPhase is not a constructor**
i tried so many things but nothing is working.

and here is my script:

```
var scene, camera, renderer, world, dt, damping, helper;
function init() {
  // SCENE
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xa8def0);
  
  // CAMERA
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  
  // RENDERER
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
  initPhysics();
  animate();  
}

// FUNCTION
function initPhysics() {
  world = new CANNON.World();

  dt = 1.0/60.0;
  damping = 0.01

  world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadPhase();
  world.gravity.set(0, -10, 0);

  helper = new CannonHelper(scene, world);

  const groundShape = new CANNON.Plane();
  var groundMaterial = new CANNON.Material();
  const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass:0, material: groundMaterial});
  groundBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(1, 0, 0) - Math.PI / 2);
  groundBody.addShape(groundShape);
  world.add(groundBody);
  helper.addVisual(groundBody, 0xFFAA00);
}

function windowResize() {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}

// ANIMATE
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

Please tell me why i am having this error.

Answer (score 0):

`NaiveBroadPhase` (uppercase P) doesn't exist in the CANNON namespace/object.

Use `CANNON.NaiveBroadphase` (lowercase p)

**Tip**

To check a property:

```
console.log(CANNON.NaiveBroadPhase); // undefined
```

To check all properties:

```
console.dir(CANNON); // All properties of CANNON
```